# Flutter Android Studio - Stuck on Open File dialog box

Tags: flutter, android-studio-4.1

I was trying to continue my Flutter learning and just tried to open the project. I opened the android studio, it showed me the project that I had opened the last time. Then I proceed to File->Open to open the project I specifically used for learning (let's call it **L**). But then android studio was stuck on open file dialog box (shown in screenshot).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hvKr.jpg)

It just stuck there for more than 10 minutes, until I decided that there is something wrong and hit the cancel button. I can still access my project using File->Open Recent, though.

Questions are, what caused it? What can I do to fix it?

I've tried:

1. Uninstalling android studio and reinstalling it
2. Running disk defragment (I don't know if it is relevant. I thought that maybe something in my drive caused it)

Somehow I was able to made it past the loading when I do the following:

1. Open Java Project from Open Recent
2. Let the gradle build run, wait until gradle finish downloading files
3. Click File->Open

But when I came back to **L** from Open Recent and go to open file menu, it stuck again

I also tried googling "android studio stuck on open project screen" or "android studio cannot open file" but there's nothing I can use there

Additional Information

1. Android Studio Version 4.1
2. Flutter version 1.20.3
3. Dart SDK version 2.9.2

Please help